# Extract Images from PDF using pdfbox library java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want only images at their respective positions as in the pdf with its exact layout but I don't want text to render in it Is there any way to do it currently I am working in this way but text also coming in this way so is there any way to meet that requirement

```
             File sourceFile=new File(pdfFile);
             String fileName = sourceFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");             
             int pageNumber = 1;
             for (PDPage page : li) 
             {
                 BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage();
                 File outputfile = new File(imgDes + fileName +"_"+ pageNumber +".png");
                 System.out.println("Image Created -> "+ outputfile.getName());
                 ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
                 pageNumber++;
             }
```

Comment: Assuming you mean "converting to images" and not "extracting the images": the problem with the 1.8 versions is that PDFBox can't render certain embedded Type1 fonts correctly, that is why your pages are blank. This will be solved in the unreleased version 2.0. (This is already available with svn, but still in development)

Comment: i want to extract images in a page but not the text i do want entire pdf page as image but with out text only images with in it

Comment: Your comment contradicts itself: (1) "Extracting images" means that you'd get one file per image, thus several files per page if there are several images on a specific page. (2) Your text "i do want entire pdf page as image but with out text only images with in it" would mean that if there are several images in one PDF page, you'd want one image per page, and that image having the PDF images from that page, but without the text. If it is (2): what about lines and shapes or shadings or patterns? Do you want them or not?

Comment: no i mean to say that I want only images at their respective positions  as in the pdf with its exact layout but I don't want text to render in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive a class from PageDrawer and override all methods that don't deal with images with empty, and then call drawPage(). I just overrode processTextPosition(), and didn't bother about lines, shapes etc but I think it is clear what I mean.

```
public class MyPageDrawer extends PageDrawer
{

    public MyPageDrawer() throws IOException
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)
    {
    }

    // taken from PDPage.convertToImage, with extra parameter and one modification
    static BufferedImage convertToImage(PDPage page, int imageType, int resolution) throws IOException
    {
        final Color TRANSPARENT_WHITE = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);
        final int DEFAULT_USER_SPACE_UNIT_DPI = 72;

        PDRectangle cropBox = page.findCropBox();
        float widthPt = cropBox.getWidth();
        float heightPt = cropBox.getHeight();
        float scaling = resolution / (float) DEFAULT_USER_SPACE_UNIT_DPI;
        int widthPx = Math.round(widthPt * scaling);
        int heightPx = Math.round(heightPt * scaling);
        Dimension pageDimension = new Dimension((int) widthPt, (int) heightPt);
        int rotationAngle = page.findRotation();
        // normalize the rotation angle
        if (rotationAngle < 0)
        {
            rotationAngle += 360;
        }
        else if (rotationAngle >= 360)
        {
            rotationAngle -= 360;
        }
        // swap width and height
        BufferedImage retval;
        if (rotationAngle == 90 || rotationAngle == 270)
        {
            retval = new BufferedImage(heightPx, widthPx, imageType);
        }
        else
        {
            retval = new BufferedImage(widthPx, heightPx, imageType);
        }
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) retval.getGraphics();
        graphics.setBackground(TRANSPARENT_WHITE);
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, retval.getWidth(), retval.getHeight());
        if (rotationAngle != 0)
        {
            int translateX = 0;
            int translateY = 0;
            switch (rotationAngle)
            {
                case 90:
                    translateX = retval.getWidth();
                    break;
                case 270:
                    translateY = retval.getHeight();
                    break;
                case 180:
                    translateX = retval.getWidth();
                    translateY = retval.getHeight();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            graphics.translate(translateX, translateY);
            graphics.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rotationAngle));
        }
        graphics.scale(scaling, scaling);
        PageDrawer drawer = new MyPageDrawer(); // MyPageDrawer instead of PageDrawer
        drawer.drawPage(graphics, page, pageDimension);
        drawer.dispose();
        graphics.dispose();
        return retval;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String filename = "......./blah.pdf";

        // open the document
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(filename), null);
        List<PDPage> pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int p = 0; p < pages.size(); ++p)
        {
            PDPage page = pages.get(p);
            BufferedImage bim = convertToImage(page, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300);

            boolean b = ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, "page-" + (p + 1) + ".png", 300);
            if (!b)
            {
                // error handling
            }
        }
        doc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: can I get size of extracted images as exactly the size of pdf pages??

Comment: Is this a new question? If you have several images on a PDF, it would make no sense to change the size of all of them to the size of the PDF page. And what if the size doesn't have the same x/y ratio as the PDF page? If you really want to do that, then it would be easier to just extract the images as shown in the source code ExtractImages.java and then create a new PDF from there, see the ImageToPDF.java example.

Comment: For one pdf it is giving error as SEVERE: Something went wrong ... the pixelmap doesn't contain any data. it is extracting only the layout as white coloured one any solution for this is helpful for me

Comment: This is a follow up error. Did you include a JBIG plugin jar in your classpath? https://pdfbox.apache.org/dependencies.html

Comment: You'll also need JAI (jai_imageio.jar) if your PDF files have JPEG2000 encoded images.

Comment: I just need to add those jars only ? I am adding those two jars but the same thing happening org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap getRGBImage SEVERE: Something went wrong ... the pixelmap doesn't contain any data.

Comment: There must be another error message... make sure you're using the latest version (1.8.8). If it still doesn't work, upload the file to a public place.